# How do we use same WKWebView for multiple UITab

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I want to create an app with multiple tab bar. But each tabs, i am going to use Web view.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use same WKWebView(Reuse)?. How do I do that?.

Can someone help me with best approach. I am new to swift and iOS.

Comment: No there is no such provision to reuse WKWebView. You have to create new instance of web view wherever you want to use.

Comment: Are you sure you need to reuse it? Every time you change the tab `WKWebView` will take a time to render the web content. And in the future when you'll need to work with `WKWebView` delegates there will be a lot of headaches with this.

But in general, yes, you can reuse it by saving an instance of `WKWebView` with the current config and send it with navigation, or implementing `NSCopying` and make a copy of `WKWebView`.

Comment: I presume that you can do it with `UIDocument`.

Comment: @Andrew: It means better to use different/new object for each tab?. Yes I am completely depends on delegate methods, since I need to handle JS to Native communication for each screen.

Comment: Not exactly , I want to reuse it. I need a better suggestion. Whether I should reuse the webview or each native menus's(tab) I recreate webview?.

My use case,
1. Render webpage on each tabs.
2. Handle action from webview to Native and vice versa.

Comment: @Bob, please describe, what a point in reuse WebView, why it's so important? Because how I see you just need to manage interaction with `WKWebView`. If you need that all these tab communications between them, just create some sort of state manager that can handle some change on each of the tab and transit this state to the next one.  Because now, according to your use cases, I don't see any pros for reusing one instance of web view. Sorry, maybe I just can't see whole situation.

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you Andrew. Main reason(Resuse webView)  - "How to share cookies and is it a good design approach?" . May be, I am completely wrong. Even if I don't go with reuse mode, I could share the cookie.

My use case:
1. Communicate between native screen and WebViews
2. All session(for example after Login in) screens basically build in HTML + Javascript, and using WebViews, I will render. 
3. I am considering to use native menu's(like UITabbar) and each view will render my html using WebViews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So how I see, your biggest problem, that why you want to reuse `WKWebView` on every tab is sharing cookies:

In this case, we can avoid reuse and create a kind of cookie manager:

```
// SharedCookieManager.swift


final class SharedCookieManager: NSObject {
    
    // Singleton manager
    static let `default` = SharedCookieManager()
    private override init() { super.init() }
    
    // All cookies taht we have on every WKWebView
    var cookies: Set<HTTPCookie> = []
    // Callback helping to observe changes in our set
    var cookieUpdateCallback: ((_ cookies: [HTTPCookie]) -> Void)?
    
    // Append method
    func appendCookies(_ cookies: [HTTPCookie]) {
        cookies.forEach({ [weak self] in
            self?.cookies.insert($0)
        })
    }
}
```

Use cases of our manager:

```
// FirstTabViewController.swift

class FirstTabViewController: UIViewController, WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver {
    
    var webView: WKWebView? {
        didSet {
            SharedCookieManager.default.cookieUpdateCallback = { [weak self] newCookies in
                self?.webView?.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies({ oldCookies in
                    Set(newCookies).symmetricDifference(oldCookies).forEach({
                        self?.webView?.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie($0, completionHandler: nil)
                    })
                    self?.webView?.reload()
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.add(self)
        let webView = WKWebView()
        
        SharedCookieManager.default.cookies.forEach({ [weak webView] in
            webView?.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie($0)
        })
    }
    
    func cookiesDidChange(in cookieStore: WKHTTPCookieStore) {
        cookieStore.getAllCookies({
            SharedCookieManager.default.appendCookies($0)
        })
    }
}
```

Same for every `ViewController` you use within `TabBar`

**It's not a "golden hammer" and I can't say it would work for 100%, but you can try to play with this sample to reach your goals. Hope it will help.**

Answer (score 0):

The same object can be used at multiple places, either you need to create a copy of the object or create a new object of the class. and implement a way to keep both in sync.